# mongodb : TableRow.TableRow is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am getting-started with mongodb.
I have set-up all the mongodb and the mongoose configuration and they work perfectly.
Here are the project files:

> server.js:

```
const TableRow = require('./models/tableRow');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors')
const express = require('express');
const mongoose= require('mongoose')
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/table', function(err) {
  if (err) { throw err; }
  console.log('Successfully connected');
});
const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log('MongoDB database connection established successfully!');
});
app.use('/', router);
router.route('/table/add').post((req, res) => {
  let tableRow = new TableRow (req.body);
  tableRow.save()
      .then(issue => {
          res.status(200).json({'tableRow': 'Added successfully'});
      })
      .catch(err => {
          res.status(400).send('Failed to create new record');
      });
});
app.listen(5757, () => console.log(`Express server running on port 5757`));
```

> tableRow.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
let TableRow = new Schema({
    column1Data: {
        type: String
    },
    column2Data: {
        type: String
    }
});
export default mongoose.model('TableRow', TableRow);
```

When I tried testing this with POSTMAN:

[image]

I get this error:

> TypeError: TableRow is not a constructor

I think the problem is with the way I required the model in server.js:

```
const TableRow = require('./models/tableRow');
```

Someone else faced a similar issue and posted it on stackOverFlow. However, they are defining the model in the same file the server code.

[Similar issue but doesn't solve my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52349100/typeerror-userschema-is-not-a-constructor-schema-is-not-a-constructor-mongodb)

So his post doesn't solve my issue.
Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change from

```
export default mongoose.model('TableRow', TableRow);
```

To this:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('TableRow', TableRow);
```

And `import` so: `const TableRow = require('./models/tableRow');`

It's CommonJS module specification which is the standard used in Node.js for working with modules ([more info](https://flaviocopes.com/commonjs/)).

When using Node.js, including express framework, you should do it so.

> *module.exports* is the object that's actually returned as the result of a *require call*.([Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5311377/11330560))

Remember:

> You must use both import and export syntax from the **same** standard.

---

A brief summary of two module systems:

*Today there are two module systems that are actively being used. CommonJS (CJS) is what Node.js has used historically. ESM (EcmaScript modules) is a newer system which has been added to the JavaScript specification. Browsers already support ES modules, and Node is adding support.* ([source](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2018/03/es-modules-a-cartoon-deep-dive/))

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly! So: module.exports is the ESM system and export default is the CJS system?

Comment: @AhmedGhrib I'm so happy it worked for you, really :) ... oh no, you got it confused there in the comment: it's vice-versa. ```module.exports``` is from CJS, and ```export default``` from ES. Checkout these links too: [link#1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21117231/11330560), [link#2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14424583/11330560), [link#3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21117231/11330560)